# jquery catching url of a load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I have a html page with link:

**page.html** (it's url is `http://myhost/home/`)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="first">Link</a>
```

**script.js:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#first').click(function() {
         $('#some_div').load('home/new/new_page.html');
         var pathname = window.loaction.pathname;
         alert(pathname);
    }
});
```

When I click on a link in `page.html`, `new_page.html` is loading into `#some_div` and it works ok. How can I catch url of a load function, so when I alert it like in the example above I will get `'/home/new/'` instead of `'/home/'` ?

Comment: As far as i understand the question, you want your pathname variable to be 'home/new/new_page.html'? jQuery load function is an ajax call, it won't change your window.location variable

Comment: i don't want to change pathname var. I want to know if it's possible to catch the url of a load function. I've added pathname variable for example. In firebug console i can see GET http://myhost/home/new/ 200 OK
  129ms

Comment: I think not. According to http://api.jquery.com/load/ the most you can get from load function is response text, status text, and XMLHttpRequest object, which doesn't have url variable, i looked it up and i saw it only has readyState, status and statusText variables.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

to

```
var pathname = window.loaction.pathname;
```